# How to optimise memory in swift while creating new storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am using localisation in my app. whenever user change language inside the application, i set the selected language and create new storyboard and make it root view controller. it's all working fine. but the issue I'm facing is that whenever i create new storyboard and make it rootviewcontroller memory usage keep on increasing e.g. at start application is using 117 MB i change the language and set new story it goes to 160-170 MB , again i change the language it goes to 220-230 MB . So how to destroy previous storyboard and create new one .

```
func makeRootViewController(controller_Identifier: String, storyboard: String?) {
    let navController = UINavigationController()
    navController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard ?? "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controller_Identifier)
    navController.viewControllers = [vc]
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.removeFromParent()
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nil
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = navController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you should using localization by code, not in storyboard. There're many ways to do it. For simplest

I refer :

- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-localize-your-ios-app
- https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift

Comment: i have done this internationalisation thing , it was working fine before , after few updates it stopped working due to that i changed the way of translation. Now on language change i want to destroy the previous storyboard and create new one . is there anyway to do that . to clear all the memory allocated by the existing storyboard .

Comment: No, I mean that, in this way, you don't need to create a new storyboard or delete one. You just need to notify to view for them to change the text.